# Images become broken at a certain point as I navigate through my site (on localhost)

Tags: java, velocity

I'm working on a project for code school and am having trouble with the images on my site. While I'm on the index and initial pages (hosted on a local server), the leaderboard, home logo, and browser tab icon all work well. Then, for certain pages, all of those images suddenly fail.

The images are part of my `layout.vtl` file, and all other Velocity templates are parsed into the main layout file. Since they're in the main layout file, I feel like they should be accessible on every page of the site.

The images are stored in `src/main/resources/public/img` .

Some clarifying information:

- I noticed that all the pages with good images are only one template deep (for example, `localhost:4567/brands` and `localhost:4567/stores`). The failing images are deeper into the site (`localhost:4567/stores/12`).
- The pages with broken images require id's; the url above is accessed through `<a href="/stores/$store.getId()">$store.getCompany()</a>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the developer tools of your web browsers say? Which URLs do the broken images reference when you right-click on them in the browser?

Comment: With Inspect Element, the imc src references the correct URL, but no longer gives a preview of the correct image (like it does on the pages with working images).I don't see any errors, other than the broken images themselves. I'm not very familiar with debugging image issues though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was adding a / so the link looks like
`<img src='/img/leaderboard.png'>`.  Without the slash, the URL is relative.  So for example, if you were at the URL `/store`, it would be looking for `/store/img/leaderboard.png` instead of `/img/leaderboard.png`.